# How to implement the navigation bar like yobongo or Pulse News on Android app

Tags: listview, navigation, android-gallery, pulse

Can anyone known how to implement the portrait navigation bar like yobongo ?
Perhaps use custom gallery or Horizontal ListView ? But when I try to use the Horizontal ListView implemented [here](http://www.dev-smart.com/?p=34), It still can't achieving my purpose.

Maybe the navigation of pulse(TOP,SOCIAL,PAGE3,NEWS as above) is implemented by custom gallery ? But I can't do it after using lots of time...

Can anyone here help me ?

(Sorry to my poor English! )

Comment: Have you got any solution? I am also looking for same.